# Find absents dictionaries in a list of it

Tags: list, python-2.7, dictionary

I need to compare two lists of dictionaries and retrieve the absence elements, "connection" is the attribute who identify the object. The other properties may vary in time.  I tried with filters and map but I'm still stuck.

input should look like this:

```
list1 = [{'username': 'user1', 'connection': "0x2083588'", 'remote': '10.0.5.251:44840','uri': 'www.google.com:443','seconds': '600'}
        ,{'username': 'user2', 'connection': "0x2a90d778'", 'remote': '10.0.5.251:44796','uri': 'mobilenetworkscoring-pa.googleapis.com:443','seconds': '600'}]


list2 = [{'username': 'user1', 'connection': "0x2083588'", 'remote': '10.0.5.251:44840','uri': 'www.google.com:443','seconds': '400'}
        ,{'username': 'user2', 'connection': "0x2a90d778'", 'remote': '10.0.5.251:44796','uri': 'mobilenetworkscoring-pa.googleapis.com:443','seconds': '400'}
        ,{'username': 'user3', 'connection': "0x2a90d678'", 'remote': '10.0.5.251:44796','uri': 'mobilenetworkscoring-pa.googleapis.com:443','seconds': '400'}]
```

the output should be like this:

```
[{'username': 'user3', 'connection': "0x2a90d678'", 'remote': '10.0.5.251:44796','uri': 'mobilenetworkscoring-pa.googleapis.com:443','seconds': '400'}]
```

Comment: Can you share what you've tried as a [mcve]? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
# Mapping the list1 by "connection" property
mapList = map(lambda y: y.get('connection'), list1)

# Filtering the elements of the second list (list2) 
# that are missing from the map of the list1 (mapList) by "connection" property
filterList = filter(lambda x: x.get('connection') not in mapList,list2)
print filterList
```

Comment: Code-only answers are generally frowned upon on this site. Could you please edit your answer to include some comments or explanation of your code? Explanations should answer questions like: What does it do? How does it do it? Where does it go? How does it solve OP's problem? See: [How to anwser](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). Thanks!